# Failing to acquire vTAP interfaces in a virtualized environment

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, ioctl, tun

**Suppose I've got the following setup:**

A **Host** which runs two KVM VMs(**VM1** and **VM2**), a virtual bridge **virbr**, and two bridge taps **vTAP1** and **vTAP2**. The VM's are attached to the vTAPS respectively.

I've got an application running on the host which measures different load metrics on the bridge. For achieving this it needs to acquire the vTAPS in order to stream the packets between the vTAPs through the bridge for measurement.
The **problem** is that I can't acquire the vTAPS, because the *ioctl* *TUNSETIFF* syscall fails with **EBUSY** errno.
I guess that it happens because the application(**runned on the host**) is not the owner of the taps(**which owned by the VMs**). Adding new temporary bridge vTAPS for measurement may not be always a solution because sometimes I would want to measure the flow directly between the VM vTAPS.
**Attempted solution:** There is a *Multiqueue tuntap interface*:

> Linux supports multiqueue tuntap which can use multiple
>     file descriptors (queues) to parallelize packets sending or receiving. The
>     device allocation is the same as before, and if user wants to create multiple
>     queues, TUNSETIFF with the same device name must be called many times with
>     IFF_MULTI_QUEUE flag.

using **IFF_MULTI_QUEUE** stopped the *ioctl* from failing with **EBUSY** errno but it started failing on *write* syscall to the vTAP with **EINVAL** errno. So it didn't really solve anything.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.